# Preventing escaping at shell in script with multiple levels of quotes

Tags: linux, bash, shell

I'd like to append the following lines to the end of my .zshrc file in an install script that is run:

```
export PATH="$HOME/.rbenv/bin:$PATH"
eval "$(rbenv init -)"
```

The .zshrc file has write only access by root, and I am another user (but with sudo access).

One way to do it is similar to the following:

```
sudo bash -c "echo 'export PATH=\"$HOME/.rbenv/bin:$PATH\"' >> ~/.zshrc"
```

The main problem is that the $HOME and $PATH fields, as well as the $() section are then inserted after being replaced with the interpreted values. I could put a single quote on the outside, but I need to use a double quote where the first single quote is currently, which then interprets the inside.

I'd appreciate any help about how to do this without interpreting the variables/commands before insertion. Is a heredoc an easier way to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Escape variable expansion by placing `\` before `$`:

```
sudo bash -c "echo 'export PATH=\"\$HOME/.rbenv/bin:\$PATH\"' >> ~/.zshrc"
```

Answer (score 0):

Just use the correct quotes. And don't be afraid to switch between them.

```
sudo bash -c "echo 'export "'PATH="$HOME/.rbenv/bin:$PATH"'"'" >> ~/.zshrc"
```

Comment: You have odd number of `"`. I don't think that your example works.